# Beanshell jdbc connection

Tags: java, jdbc, beanshell

i want to connect to my database using beanshell script. my code works with java but beanshell doesn't work with the same code. Class not found exception will be thrown. does it have other usage or can't i connect to database with beanshell?

Thanks,
Bilal

---

@ Plínio Pantaleão
the code is like this

```
addClassPath("C:\\mysql-connector-java-5.1.13\\mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar");
import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
import java.sql.Connection;

Connection conn = null;

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

and the exception is

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.bsh.Reflect.invokeMethod(Reflect.java:134)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.bsh.Reflect.invokeStaticMethod(Reflect.java:98)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.bsh.Name.invokeMethod(Name.java:871)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(BSHMethodInvocation.java:75)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.bsh.BSHPrimarySuffix.doSuffix(BSHPrimarySuffix.java:102)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:80)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:47)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:644)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:738)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:727)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.BeanShellFacade._eval(BeanShellFacade.java:148)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.BeanShellFacade.eval(BeanShellFacade.java:113)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.BeanShellFacade.evalSelection(BeanShellFacade.java:85)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.BeanShell.evalSelection(BeanShell.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.bsh.Reflect.invokeMethod(Reflect.java:134)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.bsh.Reflect.invokeStaticMethod(Reflect.java:98)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.bsh.Name.invokeMethod(Name.java:871)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(BSHMethodInvocation.java:75)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:102)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:47)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.bsh.BSHBlock.evalBlock(BSHBlock.java:130)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.bsh.BSHBlock.eval(BSHBlock.java:80)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.bsh.BshMethod.invokeImpl(BshMethod.java:362)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.bsh.BshMethod.invoke(BshMethod.java:258)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.bsh.BshMethod.invoke(BshMethod.java:186)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.BeanShellFacade.runCachedBlock(BeanShellFacade.java:225)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.BeanShell.runCachedBlock(BeanShell.java:423)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.BeanShellAction.invoke(BeanShellAction.java:73)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.gui.InputHandler.invokeAction(InputHandler.java:352)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.jEdit$4.invokeAction(jEdit.java:3255)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.jEdit$4.invokeAction(jEdit.java:3237)
at org.gjt.sp.jedit.EditAction$Wrapper.actionPerformed(EditAction.java:221)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you post the code (script and classpath config) and the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ClassNotFoundException` simply means that the in the message mentioned class is missing in the runtime classpath. Just [add](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/classpath.html#Changing_the_Class_Path) the JDBC driver JAR file to the runtime classpath of the beanshell script. Here's an extract of the documentation:

> ### [Changing the Class Path](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/classpath.html#Changing_the_Class_Path)
>
> #### addClassPath( URL | path )
>
> Add the specified directory or archive to the classpath. Archives may be located by URL, allowing them to be loaded over the network.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> addClassPath( "/home/pat/java/classes" );
> addClassPath( "/home/pat/java/mystuff.jar" );
> addClassPath( new URL("http://myserver/~pat/somebeans.jar") );
> ```

Then, to load the driver class, you [need](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/classpath.html#Loading_Classes_Explicitly) to use Beanshell's provided `getClass()` method instead of the standard `Class#forName()`. Here's an extract of the documentation:

> ### [Loading Classes Explicitly](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/classpath.html#Loading_Classes_Explicitly)
>
> In order to perform an explicit class lookup by name while taking into account any BeanShell class path modification you must use a replacement for the standard `Class.forName()` method.
>
> The `getClass()` command will load a class by name, using the BeanShell classpath. Alternately, you can consult the class manager explicitly:
>
> ```
> name="foo.bar.MyClass";
> c = getClass( name );
> c = BshClassManager.classForName( name );  // equivalent
> ```

Comment: @BalusC, i have already added the classpath. however it didn't work.

Comment: Then you did something wrong. It's hard to tell what based on the little information given as far.

Comment: What i have done are:
1- I have copied Jar folder to beanshells lib directory
2- I have added the classpath like this addClassPath( "/home/pat/java/mystuff.jar" );
3- I have importet the library
i used external libraries many times like this

Comment: i have controlled everything. i am sure i must do something else.

Comment: the error is in this line Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

com.mysql.jdbc.Driver is not found
but if i instance new Driver like Driver d = new Driver(); it works
if it was import failure, that would not work too.

Comment: You can't use `Class#forName()` in bsh. See also the same documentation. I've updated the answer.

Comment: It Works!
Thanks @BalusC it was because of loading class.